# React js converting closing tags to unreachable code when i try to add jsx or markup in middle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react-js, this is my code, when i am trying to add either markup or jsx in the given space 'write code', my editor is showing syntax errors and disabling closing div tags, and throwing unreachable code error, in few cases it asking to close form tag though it already closed.

```
render() {
    const {patientsList} = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
          <NavBar />
        <form style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}>
          { patientsList.length === 0 ? (
            <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center", flexGrow: "1" }}>
              No Patients Found
            </h1>
          ) : (
          {/*Write code here to create all patients details*/}
          // <table>
          //  <tr><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>email</th><th>dob</th><th>location</th><th>mobile</th></tr>
          // </table>
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
 }
```

The table tag section was deliberately commented by me to post that section here. I would like to know my mistake and like to find out what is the main reason for this and how to avoid such issues in the future.

Comment: Are the `//` on purpose? Because you can't use them in JSX

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `{}` from this code:

```
const { patientsList } = this.state;

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <NavBar />
      <form style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}>
        {patientsList.length === 0 ? (
          <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center", flexGrow: "1" }}>
            No Patients Found
          </h1>
        ) : (
          <div>Write code here!</div>
            /*Write code here to create all patients details*/
          // <table>
          //  <tr><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>email</th><th>dob</th><th>location</th><th>mobile</th></tr>
          // </table>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: removing flower braces works, but i would like to know why it isn't considered as jsx comment

Answer (score 0):

`//` is not a syntax for comments in jsx. You have to add the comments like

```
{/*

  ... Commented Code

*/}
```

So do this

```
render() {
    const {patientsList} = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
          <NavBar />
        <form style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}>
          { patientsList.length === 0 ? (
            <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center", flexGrow: "1" }}>
              No Patients Found
            </h1>
          ) : (
          {/*Write code here to create all patients details
           <table>
            <tr><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>email</th><th>dob</th><th>location</th> 
            <th>mobile</th></tr>
           </table>
           */}
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like that:

```
render() {
    const {patientsList} = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
          <NavBar />
        <form style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}>
          { patientsList.length === 0 ? (
            <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center", flexGrow: "1" }}>
              No Patients Found
            </h1>
          ) : (
          <>
            <div>Any info here</div>
            <table>
             <tr><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>email</th><th>dob</th><th>location</th><th>mobile</th></tr>
             </table>
           </>
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    );
 }
```

You must always return one **and only one** node in JSX, in your case you have 2 nodes: `table` and `div`. So in order to make a single node, you can use `<> </>` or `React.Fragment`. You can find more info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Comment: Another link worth to read: [click me](https://scotch.io/tutorials/why-you-cant-return-parallel-jsx-elements-the-hack)

Comment: I am only delivering a single node div, the entire part is wrapped inside div and I am using a ternary operator inside form data, but thanks for your share on react fragments